# How do I sum the cells of one column based on unique duplicate rows of other columns?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, duplicates, google-sheets-formula, countif

I need column D summed wherever column A-C are identical. Column E is what I want the output to look like. I am only using google sheet functions right now and have not learned how to write script. This formula is the closest I've gotten.

```
=SUM(filter(D:D;COUNTIF(A2:A&B:B&C:C;A2:A&B:B&C:C)>1))
```

However, it does not distinguish between different text strings only sums any duplicate.

Thanks for any help!

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| papaya | 10/10/2022 | 500 | 42 | 42 |
| papaya | 15/12/2022 | 550 | 30 | 59 |
| papaya | 15/12/2022 | 550 | 29 | 59 |
| Pineapple | 16/11/2022 | 400 | 55 | 55 |
| Pineapple | 09/11/2022 | 400 | 63 | 78 |
| Pineapple | 09/11/2022 | 400 | 15 | 78 |

Comment: Tried `SUMIFS`?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(A:E; "select A,B,C,sum(D) where D is not null group by A,B,C label sum(D)''")
```

---

### update

use in M2:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(bc; g; i; IFERROR(g/VLOOKUP(bc; QUERY({bc\i*1}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"); 2; )))
 (B2:B&C2:C; G2:G; I2:I))
```

[image]

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for but it helps point me in the right direction. I'm trying to find a formula that will replace Column E fill each cell with what I have already typed. 
This Formula 
=QUERY(A:E; "select A,B,C,sum(D) where D is not null group by A,B,C label sum(D)''")
essentially sums the unique rows. I need it to output that sum of each unique row into every corresponding cell.

Comment: @CalebW. can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/187MZFhP4cHzIMK1-xHr4QUcV90Q4ERgbp_bjlRTIlp4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @CalebW. sheet is private

Comment: Oh yeah, oops. I gave it access to anyone with the link.